# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null value not allowed as an environment variable: POM_PACKAGING

Tags: maven, jenkins

Just spent 2 hours on this, running a Maven project from Jenkins.

All you need to do is run in your Jenkins Master:
rm -rf jenkins/jobs/[project_name]/modules/*

after that you must(!!!) restart Jenkins.

Rerun your job, it should work.

Comment: This isn't a question

Answer (score -2, accepted):

hopes this helps. the answer was found in:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-issues/GeOGjbDwPmU